# What is the difference between these two MySQL queries?

Tags: mysql, join

```
SELECT COUNT( companyId )
FROM Companies
 LEFT JOIN Cities ON Cities.cityId = Companies.cityId
GROUP BY Companies.companyId;
```

## VS

```
SELECT COUNT( companyId )
FROM Cities
 LEFT JOIN Companies ON Cities.cityId = Companies.cityId
GROUP BY Companies.companyId;
```

What is the difference?

Comment: Have you ran them both?

Comment: Look up what the LEFT in LEFT JOIN means and you'll have your answer.

Comment: Please read about MySQL left join definitely you'll have the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first query left table is Companies and in the second query  Cities.

> The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all rows from the left table
>   (table_name1), even if there are    no matches in the right table
>   (table_name2).

FIRST QUERY

> The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all rows from the Companies table
>   , even if there are    no matches in the Cities table

SECOND QUERY

> The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all rows from the Cities  table
>   , even if there are    no matches in the Companies  table

[Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Answer (score 1):

I'm just placing a picture (self explained)

**MySQL left JOIN**

[image]